# How to analyse and work with a Android Project without Documentation?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, code-analysis

I got a Project from my Company without Documentation. Now I have to add some things to this Project like new Add features etc. But I have no clue how this Project is organized and where it starts... Does anyone know how to work with a Project like this? Can I analyse it with a shema?

How can i find the startpoint of this application?

and is there a way to debug from A to Z?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the manifest file for the main activity.

While others may chime in with Android-specific answers, you should think of handling this project as "legacy code" -- created by someone else, with poor or no documentation, and little idea (initially) of how things were implemented.

Check out [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) by Feathers if you'd like a decent book on your problem. Also relevant, but not Android-specific, is advice in the ebook "Rails Rescue" and the "Legacy Code" chapter in Rails Test Prescriptions. Though Rails-related, the advice the authors give is directly applicable to most projects.

In a nutshell:

- get the project under version control if it isn't already (and if it is, you're in luck, as you can review the commit history to get a feel for things)
- get the test suite running cleanly. No test suite? Get a simple test stub started
- commit yourself to creating tests for every new feature you implement

Lastly, *read the code*. You're going to have to bite the bullet and familiarize yourself with the implementation -- there's no way around that.

Comment: I dont excactly get your point with the test suite.. can you explain this a little? and nope there is no version control of this application... :S

Comment: Aytac, *get the project under version control* before you make any changes. Next, educate yourself about testing Android applications and JUnit.

Answer (score 2):

The start point (The main activity) of the application can be found in the manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Whichever activity has this intent-filter is the entry point of the app

Comment: thanks this was usefull too, but didn't answer my whole question. that's why I only can give you a +1

Answer (score 0):

check in Manifest.xml the `<activity>` lines someone should got

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

this is where the apk starts

then i would start at the `onCreate()` method of this class. You should also check for a Service that maybe starts when the device boots.
Check for a `BroadcastReceiver` and something like this

```
 if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))
```

Answer (score 0):

As JesperB said, find the start activity in the manifest.

Then I would run the app in debug mode and just follow where everything leads as you use the app, making notes along the way.

You might also try running the view heirarchy viewer on it, that could provide some direction too.